# lodash's isElement equivalent in pure JS

Tags: javascript, object-detection, instanceof, typechecking, htmlelements

Right now I am using [`isElement`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isElement) by [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to check if an element is DOM likely. I want to get rid of this library so I am looking for a pure JS implementation of this function.

I'm using this, but I don't know if it's the right implementation and if I'm ignoring any edge cases:

```js
const isDOMElement = el => el instanceof HTMLElement
```

---

###### **Update**

I have tested ([codepen link](https://codepen.io/mickiticki/pen/QWaXjZO)) the four proposed implementation, in all cases is working as expected, maybe the one proposed by [@cesare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13478993/cesare-polonara) covers most of the cases, but also the one proposed by [@peter-seliger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2627243/peter-seliger) is clever and work with an "outside of the BOX" thinking. Finally, both [@David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) and the one I firstly use,  works for most of the cases.

So in conclusion I think, as David Thomas points `It's just a matter of preference`.

*P.S: The tags used for the test are extracted from MDN's [HTML elements reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)*

*P.S2: Not sure on how to proceed and what answer accept. Both cesare and peter have a good point*

Comment: I don’t know about the edge-cases, hence my not answering, but I’d personally go with `const isDOMElement = el => el.nodeType && el.nodeType === 1`. But as for why, or “is it better” I have no idea, and it’s just a matter of preference.

Comment: @David Thomas Though unlikely, you could have an object with a nodeType property of 1 not being a DOM element. Checking properties is not as safe as checking if an object is an instance of a certain constructor to me.

Comment: Have you looked at the lodash source code to simply see what they're doing?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the code, but the implementation is based on more library methods, so I wanted to look for an implementation of my own. @DavidThomas thank you for the proposed implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `lodash` util:

```
function isElement(value) {
  return isObjectLike(value) && value.nodeType === 1 && !isPlainObject(value)
}
```

Basically with `isObjectLike` it checks that the value passed is a non `null` object ( since null is an object in js ) and with `!isPlainObject` that it is not a plain object ( since it could be an object carrying a *"nodeType": 1* entry and because an HTMLElement instance has nested protos.

The `isPlainObject` util is this:

```
function isPlainObject(value) {
  if (!isObjectLike(value) || getTag(value) != '[object Object]') {
    return false
  }
  if (Object.getPrototypeOf(value) === null) {
    return true
  }
  let proto = value
  while (Object.getPrototypeOf(proto) !== null) {
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)
  }
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(value) === proto
}
```

As you can see the first check is redundant since it checks `isObjectLike` again, but the main caveat in my opinion is that it doesn't cover other objects case, since for example "Arrays" are objects too hence they pass the check:

```
const arr = [1, 2]; // array
arr.nodeType = 1; // add nodeType property to the array object
console.log(isElement(arr)); // true Lodash
```

Try it yourself.

I think it's  safer to check if the object has a `nodeType` property that is inherited:

```
const _isElement = (node) =>
    typeof node === 'object' &&
    node !== null &&
    !node.hasOwnProperty('nodeType') &&
    node.nodeType &&
    node.nodeType === 1
  

const el = document.createElement('h1'); // node
const arr = [1, 2]; // array
arr.nodeType = 1; // add nodeType property to the array object

console.log(isElement(arr)); // true Lodash
console.log(isElement(el)); // true Lodash

console.log(_isElement(arr)) // false
console.log(_isElement(el)) // true
```

In any case I prefer using your check which already covers most of those checks since any primitive non object is not instance of HTMLElement, null is not instance of HTMLElement, and an HTMLElement instance has a "nodeType" poperty but it is inherited from proto and not an own property, :

```
const isDOMElement = el => el instanceof HTMLElement
//or
const isDOMElement = el => el instanceof Node
```

Comment: Bear in mind that their method relies on two other methods (of their own), so that would also have to be referenced in OP’s own implementation. But, otherwise, yeah: this seems a good way to go.

Comment: Yeah I checked those methods and they are pretty trivial, `isObjectLike` is something like `typeof o === "object"` :-)

Comment: So, from what I understand, `instaceof HTMLElement` or `el.nodeType && el.nodeType === 1`  covers all these cases, right?

Comment: I edited the answer with some trials and tests.

Answer (score 3):

One could give a try to ...

```js
function exposeImplementation(value) {
  return Object
    .prototype
    .toString
    .call(value);
}
function getInternalClassName(value) {
  return (/^\[object\s+(?<className>[^\]]+)\]$/)
    .exec(
      exposeImplementation(value)
    )
    ?.groups
    ?.className;
}
function isHTMLElement(value) {
  return !!value && (/^HTML(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)?Element$/)
    .test(
      String(
        getInternalClassName(value)
      )
    );
}

console.log(
  getInternalClassName(document.createElement('h1')),
  isHTMLElement(document.createElement('h1'))
);
console.log(
  getInternalClassName(document.body),
  isHTMLElement(document.body)
);
console.log(
  getInternalClassName(document),
  isHTMLElement(document)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: From what I understand this implementation is based on running regex on the prototypes of the elements and from there, determine if they are or not, right? It is very interesting, since the element's name always keeps the HTML...Element, very clever!

Comment: (1) The base is the explicit delegation of an object/value to [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#using_tostring_to_detect_object_class) via e.g. ... `Object.prototype.toString.call(value)` ... which unveils the object's/value's internal class name. It is a viable approach as long as one can be sure that this string value was not overwritten by `myInstance[Symbol.toStringTag]` which for `HTMLElement` instances can be safely assumed. (2) The rest indeed is based on two regex operations.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the implementation from library source code:

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/isElement.js